# SSH timeout does not happen and not disconnect

Tags: openssh

I am running ssh command from Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and `mobaxterm` v21.5 and I am trying to connect a Linux board which has kernel 4.9.

I have configured in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

on the linux board.

After 60 sec, Its disconnecting only in openssh 8.0 version, but not disconnecting in 8.2,8.5,8.7,8.9 version. Is it bug in version in 8.2. 8.5, 8.7. 8.9?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH ClientAliveCountMax setting does not seem to work and to disconnect the user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585862/ssh-clientalivecountmax-setting-does-not-seem-to-work-and-to-disconnect-the-user)

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct options? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/what-do-options-serveraliveinterval-and-clientaliveinterval-in-sshd-config-d

Comment: Welcome to the site. It seems you are working from two accounts. Please see [the help center topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to merge them.

Answer (score 0):

> after specified time in ClientAliveInterval /etc/ssh/sshd_config

What value have you configured? [sshd manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) states following:

```
ClientAliveInterval
Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been 
received from the client, sshd(8) will send a message through the
encrypted channel to request a response from the client. The default is 0,
indicating that these messages will not be sent to the client.
This option applies to protocol version 2 only.
```

If you want connection to time out, sounds like default value is the way to go.

Note session keepalive is [also configured](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) on the connecting *client* side in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
ServerAliveInterval
Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been
received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message through the
encrypted channel to request a response from the server. The default is 0,
indicating that these messages will not be sent to the server.
This option applies to protocol version 2 only.
```

Eg myself *don't want* ssh sessions to time out, which is why I have following in my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 15
  ServerAliveCountMax 3
```

---

[Related thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3027/47501)

Answer (score 0):

The man page for the `sshd_config` file (Openssh v8.6p1) says at the end of the description for `ClientAliveCountMax`:

```
 Setting a zero ClientAliveCountMax disables connection termination.
```

Your `ClientAliveCountMax 0` setting is preventing the disconnections.  Try the default of `3` (as laur already suggested), or at least `1`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can just use bash script to kill ssh connection that is idle and set this bash script to run on crontab every minutes. just change the value below.. to your preferred idle time to kill ssh connection 1800sec = 30minutes

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get the idle information from "w" command#
idle_info=$(w)

# Loop through each line of idle information#
while IFS= read -r line; do
  # Extract the username, terminal, and idle time from the line
  username=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
  terminal=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')
  idle_time=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g')

  # Check if the terminal is an SSH session and the idle time exceeds 30 minutes (1800 seconds)#
  if [[ "$terminal" =~ ^pts/ ]] && (( $(echo "$idle_time > 1800" | bc -l) )); then
    # Terminate the SSH session#
    sudo pkill -9 -t "$terminal"
    echo "Killed SSH session for user $username on terminal $terminal (Idle for $idle_time seconds)"
  fi
done <<< "$idle_info"
```