# Checking ssh connection

Tags: ssh, sshd

Is it possible to detect the activity of the ssh connection when the connection is broken.
I connect to the server via phone (ssh client) and turn off the internet, but the system (w, netstat) says I'm still on the server. Is it possible to immediately determine the activity or wait for a timeout?

Comment: A broken connection can be detected only when data is sent. See https://patrickmn.com/aside/how-to-keep-alive-ssh-sessions/

Answer (score 0):

For the server see `man 5 sshd_config`, options [`ClientAliveInterval`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ClientAliveInterval) and [`ClientAliveCountMax`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ClientAliveCountMax). If you want the server to detect when a connection breaks then you need to use these options in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server machine.

For the client see `man 5 ssh_config`, options [`ServerAliveInterval`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ServerAliveInterval) and [`ServerAliveCountMax`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ServerAliveCountMax). If you want the client to detect when a connection breaks then you need to use these options in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or in `~/.ssh/config` on the client machine, or in the command line while starting the connection (`ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=… -o ServerAliveCountMax=…`).

Read [this another answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585887/108618), it elaborates and gives few interesting links. Note the OP there wants to disconnect an idle user (which is *not* a job for `ClientAlive*`/`ServerAlive*` mechanisms), while you want to detect a broken connection (which is *exactly* the job of the mechanisms).